# Creating a usable extension

Tags: c#, lightswitch-2012

I have followed [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290140.aspx) to create a custom extension for Visual Studio Lightswitch 2012.
This extension involved creating a custom data type.

I ran it in debug which brought up an "experimental" VS2012 window, and the extension seemed to work fine after a little debugging.

My question is how can I actually use this extension in my real projects?

I have a bunch of project folders that were created near the start of the walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps under 'To Distribute An Extension' found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674923.aspx

> To distribute an extension
>
> 1. Open the \bin\Debug folder of the .Vsix project for your extension, and select the .vsix file.
> 2. Copy the file to a network share or to removable media.
> 3. On a target computer where LightSwitch is installed, open the .vsix file.
> 4. In the Visual Studio Extension Installer dialog box, choose Install.
>
> The next time that you start LightSwitch, the extension should be
>   available for use.